# Print Fibonacci Sequence to (n)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, fibonacci

I was asked to print a list to the console of the Fibonacci sequence up to a given number.

It took me a while to come up with a solution, and I'm happy to have written something that works.

I struggled with trying to incorporate *while* loop, and ended up using a for loop with an *if* statement.

I have two questions:

1. Is it sensible to try this with a while loop?
2. How could one create this sequence without a preset array with the first two numbers in the sequence?

Thank you!
By the way, this is my first post to StackOverflow, so any feedback on posting etiquette would be appreciated as well.

```
function fibbonaciToNum(num) {
    let current = 0;
    let arr = [0, 1];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        current = arr[i] + arr[i - 1]
        if (current <= num) {

            arr.push(current);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(fibbonaciToNum(34));
```

Comment: To be honest more or less the sole purpose of why students are given Fibonacci sequence is to make them learn how recursion works. I'd look into that, but kudos for creativity.

Comment: The loop condition having `arr.length` in it, and then pushing to the array in the loop, is a bit misleading, as this is unexpected for someone reading the code (the code `for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)` is just so stereotypical, that people go in with the expectancy of `arr.length` being static). However, there is no bug doing it your way. A `while` alternative would be `let next; while ((next = arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2]) <= num) arr.push(next);`. I don't think there is any issue with having a preset for the first two.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible to use while loop, and I that in this case it would be recomended.

```js
const fib = (upTo) => {
    let n1=0, n2=1, n3;
    n3 = n1 + n2; 
    while (n3 <= upTo) {
        console.log(n3); 
        n1 = n2;  
        n2 = nextTerm; 
        n3 = n1 + n2; 
    }
}
```

2. Fibonacci series is also defined by an very long and hard equation which does not depend on previous elements of sequence. So theoretically, yes, it is possible, but I would highly advise against it.